# Query returns result for int not for string

Tags: php, sql, ajax

So right now I have an ajax call which sends the ID from a button to a php script and returns the food result. If i call it by using ItemID and an int it returns the row of the itemID. However if i change it to the ItemName like below, it doesnt return any row. In the consol literally nothing is being returned when I use ItemName but if I make it print encode $ID before $STMT then it shows that the proper string is being passed

```
if(isset($_POST['ID']))
{
$ID = $_POST['ID'];

$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  group2.menu  WHERE ItemName = $ID ");

if($stmt->num_rows) 
{  
$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();

 echo $row;
print json_encode($row);    

}

}
```

AJAX if relevant

```
$('.check').click(function(){

var thisID    = $(this).attr('id');
alert(thisID);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://csmaster.sxu.edu/group2/group2/CougarLunch/retrieveColumn.php",
    data:{ ID: thisID},
    cache: false,
    async:true,
    datatype: "jsonp",
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
        // 
    }

  });
  });
```

HtML for Button First works, second doesn't

```
          <input type="checkbox" name="value" id="27" class="check">              
          <label for="27">pizza</label>

           <input type="checkbox" name="value" id="scrambled egg" class="check">             
          <label for="scrambled egg">Scrambled Egg</label>
```

Comment: You would need to have someway to associate an ID with the name. You could change the query to use a different "where" clause if it's a name or an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is ItemName a varchar field, and if so, have you tried surrounding your string with quotes?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  group2.menu  WHERE ItemName = '$ID' ");
```

Comment: I knew it was something small, originally i tried using double quotes but it didn't work and then tried
$myText = (string)$myVar;a

then i tried putting my query into single quotes and put $ID into double quotes.

none of those worked. You method did, would you know why my other methods did not work. Also thank you very much.

Comment: Depending on your DBMS, double quotes around the variable may or may not be accepted.  General practice is to use single quotes for cross-platform support.  $myText = (string)$myVar would cast your var to a string, but you'd still have the equivalent of [itemName = Scrambled Egg] in your SQL, causing an error.  'select * from table where ItemName = "$ID"' wouldn't work because the outer single quotes would prevent PHP from interpolating the $ID variable.  The SQL in that last case would literally be searching for an ItemName of "$ID" (rather than the string held within $ID).